# Convert special character in string into a char

Tags: c#

I have this string:

`string specialCharacterString = @"\n";`

where `"\n"` is the new line special character.

Is it possible convert/assign that string (of two characters) into a (single) `char`. How do I do something like:

`char specialCharacter = Parse(specialCharacterString);`

Where `specialCharacter` value would be equal to `\n`

Is there anything in dotnet that would parse the string for me or must I use `if` or `switch` the string (the string can contain any special character) to accomplish what I want. Note that `char.Parse(string)` cannot handle special characters and thinks the string above is actually two characters.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Split a string into its characters? Find non-printable characters? Do you want to find all or only the first? A single char can only hold a single character.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You have a string that contains a new line or tab character, and you want to do what with them?

Comment: You should add some code showing how you have tried to solve this.  Regular expressions seem like the best approach here but the implementation depends on what you're actually doing with the data after you capture it.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Where are you seeing this string? maybe it's actually `ab\\ndda\\tdfaff`.

Comment: Still not quite clear. You want to exchange newlines characters? Or do you have two chars '\' and 'n' and want to replace that with an actual new line?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to unescape the escaped characters in a string? And you have a string that if you looked at it in Notepad would say exactly `ab\ndda\tdfaff` ?

Comment: @Ralf Iterating over the characters I detect \ Then, I read the next character. So, I get something like \ and `n` I have two characters here. Both of them are the new line `\n` **one** special character. How do I place both of the two characters into a single character. How do I do something like `char charToProcess = slashCharacter + nLetterCharacter`

Comment: `"ab\ndda\tdfaff".Replace("\\n", "\n")` edit, well a variable containing the string, since the example string contains the literal newline and tab characters.

Comment: If you want to replace this with the newline character yes then detect those two characters and insert the single replacement newline character in a new string accordingly. At first i thought Regex.Unescape might help.

Comment: @TianoManti if that is what confuses you: `\n` is only one character, e.g. `"\n".Length == 1`. You would not have "two characters which represent the new line character", it is only one character in fact.

Comment: I have edited the original question and made it very simple and clear.

Comment: `string specialCharacterString = "\n";`, you claim that this string has 2 characters, when in fact it is only a single character: specialCharacterString.Length == 1

Comment: @knittl Corrected. Also, please take a look at my original question in the edits because I had to simplify the question because people could not get what I am trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing built into the Framework that will easily convert back and forth between characters and C# escape sequences. `Regex.Unescape` comes close, though, even if the set of characters (un)escaped is not quite the same.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you so much. All I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am oversimplifying but can't you just do the following:

txtString.Replace("\n", "$");

It is technically a string to string replacement but would be string to char...
You can always cast it to a char since you know what char you are replacing the string with.

Comment: The value for the special character string is not constant. So, replacing would mean I would replace every single one of them into a predefined character.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what business need it is, but if you need parsing C# in C# you can use some tools like Antlr, which supports C# grammar (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/)

I don't think there is any ready tool designed just for strings

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Regex.Unescape(specialCharacterString);`

It will return the new string with escape characters.

For example:

```
var literalStringWithEscapeCharacters = @"Hello\tWorld";
var stringWithEscapeCharacters = Regex.Unescape(literalStringWithEscapeCharacters);
Console.WriteLine(stringWithEscapeCharacters);
```

Will print: `Hello   World`

Instead of: `Hello\tWorld`

Then you can find escape characters in `stringWithEscapeCharacters` like this:

```
var escapeChars= new [] { '\n' };
var characters = stringWithEscapeCharacters.Where(c => escapeChars.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

All escape characters described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences

Comment: The regex unescape will also unescape `\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $, ., #` which are not normally escaped in string literals (i.e., probably not escaped in the input string), and throw an exception if it encounters `\w` or `\s`